# How to get SharePoint Custom Workflow Status With REST

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a SharePoint document library and I've created two custom workflow. Then i attached those workflows to a document library. What i'm trying to do is getting workflow status and URL with single REST API.

What I've tried is;

`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('E-Test')/items(37)?$select=DockApprove,DocSignature`

`DockApprove` and `DocSignature` is my custom created workflows, and when i run this on Chrome browser, it returns;

```
<entry xml:base="http://SPTest/_api/" m:etag=""2""...........">
    <id>Web/Lists(guid'5ddb9547-0954-4ad5-bea8-792fb16e1fab')/Items(37)</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.ESig" scheme="......."/>
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5deb9547-0954-4ed5-bef8-792fb16e1fbb')/Items(37)"/>
    <title/>
    <updated>2023-07-24T11:58:41Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name/>
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:DockApprove m:type="Edm.Int32">20</d:DockApprove>
            <d:DocSignature m:type="Edm.Int32">5</d:DocSignature>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

`DockApprove` returns 20 and `DocSignature` returns 5 which they are their status ID.
I need to get full name like "Approved", "Declined" etc.

And i need to get an URL like `http://SPTest/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List=5ddb9547-0954-4ad5-bea8-792fb16e1fab&WorkflowInstanceID=%7b..........%7d` from the REST API.

For URL, I tried to add `WorkflowInstanceID` on URL next to Select, but `WorkflowInstanceID` always returns null. Since i have multiple workflow, i also tried to expand `DockApprove` and `DocSignature`, thinking maybe i'll get URL and Status, but i could't get any result.

So is it possible to get custom workflow's status and ID or URL with single or multiple rest API request? Then users can click the URL and easily can go and check the workflow if needed.

Thank you

**Update**: I found a solution for getting workflow status as a text;

`/_api/Web/Lists(guid'......')/Items(37)/FieldValuesAsHtml?$select=DockApprove` and the return is "Approved"

Now I'm trying to get `WorkflowInstanceID` or URL for each workflow that i attached to list.

**Update**: Main idea is creating an url like `..site/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List=[ListGuid]&WorkflowInstanceID=[WF_InstanceID]` for navigating that workflow details. That's why i need WorkflowInstanceID

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getWorkflowStatus, "sp.js");  
var listTitle = 'Tutorial';  
var listItemId = 1;  
var workflowTitle = 'Approval';  

function getWorkflowStatus()  
{  
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();  
  var web = context.get_web();  
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);  
  var listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);     
  context.load(listItem);  
  context.executeQueryAsync(  
     function() {  
       var workflowStatusField = listItem.get_parentList().get_fields().getByTitle(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field  
       var workflowStatusValue = listItem.get_item(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field value  
       console.log('Approval is completed');  
     },  
    function(sender,args){  
   console.log(args.get_message());  
     }  
  );  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. How can i get a workflow instance id also? Main idea is when users clicks the url (workflow status), user can go to that workflow. 
ex: `..site/_layouts/15/WrkStat.aspx?List=[ListGuid]&WorkflowInstanceID=[WF_InstanceID]`